# Easiest way to get EC2 instance attributes within the instance itself

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Can you guys show me how to retrieve instanceId, dns public name and type of current EC2 instance from where I'm running the code...

I'm playing with `DescribeInstanceAttribute()`, but it needs to supply the instanceId to the request, and I can't find how to get the id of currently running instance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a webservice that returns machine information. Access

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id
```

To retrieve the instance id

The [Instance Metadata Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html) can be handy.

Comment: nice. So I have to make a simple `HttpWebRequest`... Thanks

Comment: Better than that, use the SDK provided by AWS for this specific purpose (See Michael Wheeler's answer below)

Comment: Note that things have been moved around since Michael's post. The .NET SDK has been updated and the properties now live in: Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata

Answer (score 17):

There's a much easier method than making a web API call, the .NET SDK.

See the [SDK documentation for EC2InstanceMetadata here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Util/TEC2InstanceMetadata.html)

For example, if you need InstanceId you can use:

```
Amazon.Util.EC2InstanceMetadata.InstanceId.ToString();
```

All the other properties are available in a similar manner.

Note that the SDK used to have Amazon.EC2.Utils - this was deprecated in 2015 and moved to Amazon.Util namespace

Comment: Seems the document listed above was moved since May 2017. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Util/TEC2InstanceMetadata.html

Comment: No need for .ToString(), .InstanceId is a string.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [AWS's Dot Net SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/Index.html) for example `Amazon.EC2.Util.EC2Metadata.InstanceId.ToString();`

Comment: Thank you sir.  I knew how to do this generically but what I really wanted was how to do it C#.

Comment: Amazon.EC2.Util is now deprecated, see my post above for current location of the properties in the .NET SDK